# Reduction of an Oxime with LiAlH4 ­­­­­­­­­

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

I want to know the mechanism of this reaction. My intuition says $\ce{H-}$ will attack on $\ce{C}$ attached to $\ce{N}$ and hydrolysis afterwards would produce $\ce{-NH-OH}$. But the answer says that the amine will be formed.